# Integration of trig - reduction formula $\int \cos^4 x\; dx$

Tags: calculus

I am not sure where I am going wrong but this problem gets more complicated

$$\int \cos^4 x\;dx
$$

$u =\cos^3 x$

$du = -3\cos^2 x \sin x \;dx$

$dv = \cos x\;dx$

$v = \sin x$

$$\sin x \cos^3 x + 3\int \sin^2x \cos^2 x \;dx$$

Now I have two squared trig functions, I can take either in the form of 1 + squared trig function but either way I get a power of 4 and nothing has gotten more simple. What is wrong?

Comment: If you write $\sin^2 x = 1-\cos^2 x$ in the last, you get $\int \cos^4 x\,dx$ back, _but with a factor_ $\neq 1$. That helps.

Comment: I dont understand.

Comment: You get $A = B + c\cdot A$. Then $(1-c)\cdot A = B$ and $A = \frac{1}{1-c}B$.

Comment: Are you trying to confuse me? I don't follow at all.

Comment: $A$ stands for $\int \cos^4 x\,dx$, the thing you want to find. $B$ is here $\sin x\cos^3 x + 3\int \cos^2 x\,dx$, and $c = -3$. If you substitute $\sin^2 x = 1 - \cos^2 x$ in the equation $\int \cos^4 x\,dx = \sin x\cos^3 x +3\int\sin^2 x\cos^2 x\,dx$ you got from partial integration, you get $\int\cos^4 x\,dx = \sin x\cos^3 x + 3\int \cos^2 x\, dx - 3\int \cos^4 x\, dx$. Move the last term to the left hand side to obtain $4\int\cos^4 x\,dx = ...$. Divide by $4$.

Comment: @Dantheman Best not to insult people trying to help you, and "Are you trying to confuse me?" might be considered insulting.

Answer (score 4):

$$\int \cos^4 x=\int{\cos^2x}\cos^2x\;dx=\int\left(\frac{1+\cos2x}{2}\right)\left(\frac{1+\cos2x}{2}\right)\;dx=\int\frac14(1+2\cos2x+\cos^22x)\;dx=\int\frac14\left(1+2\cos2x+\left(\frac{1+\cos4x}{2}\right)\right)\;dx$$

> $$\frac38x+\frac14sin(2x)+\frac{1}{32}sin(4x)+c$$

Comment: Heh, I got this same answer by writing the $z^4 = \frac{T_4(z)}{8} + \frac{T_2(z)}{2} + \frac{3}{8}$, there $T_n$ are the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind. But that was not basic calculus, so I wasn't going to post it as an answer. This computes that directly...

Comment: @Thomas Andrews:i like see your answer

Comment: It's not much more than my comment and the fact that $T_n(\cos x)=\cos nx$.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews: Thanks i got it

Answer (score 4):

Write $$I_n=\int \cos^n xdx$$ Integrate by parts with $u=\cos ^{n-1}x,dv=\cos x dx$. We get that $$I_n={\cos^{n-1}x\sin x}+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x\sin^2 xdx$$

Using $\sin^2 x=1-\cos^2x$, we obtain $$I_n={\cos^{n-1}x\sin x}+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x dx-(n-1)\int \cos^{n}x dx$$ $$I_n={\cos^{n-1}x\sin x}+(n-1)\int \cos^{n-2}x dx-(n-1)I_n $$ which gives the recursion formula  $$I_n=\frac{\cos^{n-1}x\sin x}n+\frac{n-1}n I_{n-2}$$

Use this for $n=4$.

Answer (score 2):

Try using this identity:

$$2\sin(x)\cos(x) = \sin(2x)$$

Comment: Oh I am required to have memorized all the double angle identities as well to work through these? Is there a quick way to memorize all of these? I have them on a sheet but I can only remember a few.

Comment: @Dantheman That depends on how quickly you can memorize things. I have them memorized simply from experience. Some are more useful than others so it's not necessary to memorize all of them. Here's a [list of trig identities](http://www.sosmath.com/trig/Trig5/trig5/trig5.html).

Comment: I don't see how that helps actually I don't have 2x anywhere.

Comment: @Dantheman Now you do.

Comment: How? I don't understand how  to force this into what I have.

Comment: I don't know what checyshev is.

Comment: @Dantheman $\sin(x)\cos(x)$, which you do have, becomes $\frac{1}{2}\sin(2x)$.